# change grid layout on click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

Is it possible to change a grid layout on a click event? I have a grid display of three rows and I want the grid to be changed to three columns when an item in the row is clicked.

```css
.gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridcontainer">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

On a click event on any of the items, I want the grid display to change from three rows to three columns.

Comment: Only once? or everytime you click on `item` it should get reversed from `row` to `column` and `column` to `row`.

Comment: eveytime an item is click

Comment: as there are 6 items, toggle between 3 column - 2 rows and 3 rows - 2columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make two separate classes:

```
.row {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.col {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
}
```

Toggle each class on `.gridcontainer` on each click. Details commented in demo.

```js
// Reference the .gridcontainer
var grid = document.querySelector('.gridcontainer');

// Register click event to grid callback rowCol runs on click
grid.onclick = rowCol;

/* 
Callback function rowCol() passes the Event Object...
if the clicked element (e.target) .matches() class .item...
get the clicked element's (ie .item) .closest() element .gridcontainer and 
add/remove class .col or .row
*/
function rowCol(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.item')) {
    e.target.closest('.gridcontainer').classList.toggle('row');
    e.target.closest('.gridcontainer').classList.toggle('col');
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.col {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridcontainer row">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i try that but i  get the error TypeError: grid is null, on the console. error coming form js file

Comment: @sum check the spelling of `gridcontainer` wherever it occurs in the JS, HTML, and CSS. It might serve you better if you were to change that className to something less error prone. `gridcontainer` into `grid`, or `grid-container`, or `gridContainer` .

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about how the event may look like you can see this:

```
$( "#grid" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( this ).css( "grid-template-columns", "1fr 4fr 1fr" );
});
```

and you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147528/css-grid-layout-changing-column-width-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you cloud try this pure js

```
let gridContainer = document.querySelector('.gridContainer')
gridContainer.addEventListener("click", function(){
gridContainer.classList.toggle("style_for_row"); // if active its put to off
gridContainer.classList.toggle("style_for_colomn");// and if off put to on
});  //so on every click your changing the className
```

In css you could have two classes

```
style_for_row{grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;}
style_for_column{grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;}
.gridcontainer {
 display: grid;
 justify-content: center;}
```

and html will be like

```
<div class="gridcontainer style_for_column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div></div>
```